# Submit a form with a textarea field and store value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to submit a form that contains a textarea field.

The form is part of a bigger table, with values that are submitted from the index page.

I want to submit that textarea from a different page, where the other fields are populated and update the textarea field with the submitted text from the database.

Here is how my table looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the values are already populated, excepting the PM status column.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$title = $_GET['title'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE title='".$title."'");

if($result === FALSE) { 
mysqli_error($con);
} else { 
echo '<div class="well">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 10%;">Project</th>
          <th style="width: 5%">Author</th>
          <th style="width: 10%">Topic</th>
          <th style="width: 13%">Track</th>
          <th style="width: 30%">Description</th>
          <th style="width: 22%">Screenshots</th>
          <th style="width: 5%">PM Status</th>
          <th style="width: 5%">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>';
    foreach( $result as $row ) {    
            echo '<tbody>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="color: #5584ff; font-weight: bold;"><a href="project.php?title='.$row['title'].'">' .$row['title']. '</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' .$row['author']. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$row['topic']. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$row['track']. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$row['description']. '</td>';?>
            <?php 
                if($row['file'] != '') {
                    echo '<td><a href="uploads/'.$row['file'].'"><img src="uploads/'.$row['file'].'" style="max-width: 100%;" /></a></td>';
                }
            ?>
           <?php
            echo '<form name="savestatus" id="savestatus" action="validarestatus.php" method="post">';
            echo '<td><textarea name="status" value="'.$_SESSION['status'].'" class="textarea"> '.$_SESSION['status'].' </textarea></td>';
            echo '<td><input type="submit" class="add-project" style="border: none" value="Save Status">';
            echo '</form>';
            ?>
            <?php
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tbody>';    
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
```

The page from the form action:

```
<?php
require_once('secure/config.php');

$_SESSION['status'] = addentities($_POST['status']);

if(($_SESSION['status']) == '') {
    echo "Data was not added\n";
} else 
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `projects (`status`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['status']."') WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");   
    }

    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=projects.php">';
}

$_SESSION['status'] = '';

?>
```

The addentities function:

```
function addentities($data){
   if(trim($data) != ''){
   $data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES);
   return str_replace('\\', '&#92;', $data);
   } else return $data;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what is your problem and what is your question

Comment: Why are you moving the entered data into SESSION and then blanking that same session variable at the end of the script?

Comment: Well, data from the textarea is actually not submitted to the database.

Comment: So test the status of the `mysqli_query()` call and print the error you are probably getting from the database about the query

Comment: Also what is `addentities()` thats a new one on me

Comment: I've added the addentities function to the first post.

Comment: The most important comment was the one before, about checking the status of the `mysqli_query()` call so you can look at any database errors

Comment: I've added mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); in my config.php file and it gives me no error when I submit the textarea value.

Comment: Really? Just spotted one hiccup an unmatches backtick in `INSERT INTO \`projects` (\`status\`)` it should be `INSERT INTO \`projects\` (\`status\`)`

Comment: I've solved that mistake and still doesn't add anything in the database.